# Give and example of a function such that f \in L^2(R) and f \notin L^1(R)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $L^2(R)={f:R->C| \int_{\infty}^{\infty} \mid (f(t))^2 \mid < \infty }$ and $L^1(R)={f:R->C| \int_{\infty}^{\infty} \mid (f(t)) \mid < \infty }$. Give and example of a function such that $f \in L^2(R)$ and $f \notin L^1(R)$.

Comment: Hint: it is a theorem that on compact subsets of R, the $L^2$ norm is "stronger" in the sense that an $L^2$ function on a compact set much be also in $L^1$. So any example will involve behaviour at $\infty$.

Comment: This one I disagree with the closure.  I think the question is clear.  It does sound like a standard homework and I think Jonas' answer is a good hint.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: I agree, it is a very natural question indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at a function of the form $f(x) = x^{-a}$ for some $a > 0$ on an appropriate domain.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem to me.

Comment: Maybe you're right but I cannot judge that just from the question. I will edit it a bit.

Comment: In this case, you can also look at the list of the questions by the same editor.  There has been someone asking homework questions about functional analysis for a few days.